# How to search tmux in copy-mode

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I ran Ctrl+B [ and tried using '/' (just as in vi) to search for text. But, that didn't work. I'm using iTerm on Mac but I login to a remote server and use tmux there (if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+[` then press `?` to search backwards and `/` to search forwards